# Is a CONNECT request required when connecting to an HTTPS url over TcpClient/Sockets via SOCKS proxy?

Tags: .net, proxy, tcpclient, webrequest, socks

I am trying to connect to www.google.com:443 via SOCKS5 proxy over TcpClient, but am confused on why my CONNECT request is hanging when proxied. The code provided below will work without issue until the connection is proxied via SOCKS5 (if a regular HTTP proxy is used, it will work fine).

```
Public Sub SocksProxyTest(proxy As String, proxyPort As String)
    Const host As String = "www.google.com"
    Const hostPort As Integer = 443

    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(2047) {}
    Dim bytes As Integer
    Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient(proxy, proxyPort)

    Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

    Debug.Print("negotiating socks5 connection")
    Using br = New BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.[Default], True) 
        Dim ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)(0)

        Dim auth As Byte() = New Byte() {&H5, &H1, &H0}
        Debug.Print(">> " & String.Join(" ", auth.Select(Function(b) "&H" & b.ToString("X2"))))
        stream.Write(auth, 0, auth.Length)

        Dim result As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(2)
        Debug.Print("<< &H" & result(1).ToString("X2"))

        Dim data As Byte() = {&H5, &H1, &H0, &H1, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, get_port_bytes(hostPort)(0), get_port_bytes(hostPort)(1)}
        For i As Integer = 0 To 4 - 1
            data(i + 4) = ip.GetAddressBytes()(i)
        Next
        Debug.Print(">> " & String.Join(" ", data.Select(Function(b) "&H" & b.ToString("X2"))))

        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        stream.Flush()

        result = br.ReadBytes(10)
        Debug.Print("<< &H" & result(1).ToString("X2"))

        br.Close()
    End Using
    Debug.Print("negotiated socks5 connection")

    Debug.Print("sending tunnel request")
    Dim tunnelRequest As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("CONNECT {0}:{1}  HTTP/1.1{2}Host: {0}{2}{2}", host, hostPort, vbCrLf))
    stream.Write(tunnelRequest, 0, tunnelRequest.Length)
    stream.Flush()

    bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes))

    Dim sslStream As SslStream = New SslStream(stream)
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host)

    Debug.Print("sending web request")
    Dim request As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("GET https://{0}/  HTTP/1.1" & vbCrLf & "Host: {0}" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, host))
    sslStream.Write(request, 0, request.Length)
    sslStream.Flush()

    Do
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        Debug.Print(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes))
    Loop While bytes <> 0

    client.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you sending a `CONNECT` request at all? That verb is only used when connecting through an HTTP proxy, but you are connecting through a SOCKS proxy instead.

Since you are not connecting the SOCKS proxy to an HTTP proxy, get rid of the `CONNECT` request altogether, it does not belong here.  Simply ask the SOCKS proxy to connect directly to the target host (and FYI, in SOCKS v4a and v5, you can *and should* send the target hostname to the proxy and let it resolve the IP for you, DON'T resolve it yourself, otherwise you might end up with the wrong IP, or even experience a resolution failure).

Once the proxy is connected to the target host, then communicate with the target normally as needed, as if you had connected to it directly.

Try something more like this instead:

```
Public Sub SocksProxyTest(proxy As String, proxyPort As String)
    Const host As String = "www.google.com"
    Const hostPort As Integer = 443

    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(2047) {}
    Dim bytes As Integer
    Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient(proxy, proxyPort)

    Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

    Debug.Print("negotiating socks5 connection")
    Using br = New BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.[Default], True)
        Dim auth As Byte() = New Byte() {&H5, &H1, &H0}
        Debug.Print(">> " & String.Join(" ", auth.Select(Function(b) "&H" & b.ToString("X2"))))
        stream.Write(auth, 0, auth.Length)

        Dim result As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(2)
        Debug.Print("<< &H" & result(1).ToString("X2"))

        If result(1) <> &H0 Then
            client.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim host_bytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(host)
        Dim port_bytes As Byte() = get_port_bytes(hostPort)

        Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(7 + host_bytes.Length) {}
        data(0) = &H5
        data(1) = &H1
        data(2) = &H0
        data(3) = &H3
        data(4) = CByte(host_bytes.Length)
        host_bytes.CopyTo(data, 5)
        port_bytes.CopyTo(data, 5 + host_bytes.Length)
        Debug.Print(">> " & String.Join(" ", data.Select(Function(b) "&H" & b.ToString("X2"))))

        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        stream.Flush()

        result = br.ReadBytes(4)
        Debug.Print("<< &H" & result(1).ToString("X2"))

        If result(1) <> &H0 Then
            client.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Select result(3)
            Case &H1
                br.ReadBytes(4)
            Case &H3
                br.ReadBytes(br.ReadByte())
            Case &H4
                br.ReadBytes(16)
        End Select
        br.ReadBytes(2)

        br.Close()
    End Using
    Debug.Print("negotiated socks5 connection")

    Dim sslStream As SslStream = New SslStream(stream)
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host)

    Debug.Print("sending web request")
    Dim request As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("GET / HTTP/1.1" & vbCrLf & "Host: {0}" & vbCrLf & "Connection: close" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, host))
    sslStream.Write(request, 0, request.Length)
    sslStream.Flush()

    Do
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        Debug.Print(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes))
    Loop While bytes <> 0

    client.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried your suggested changes but it never makes it beyond the call to sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient. I have tested the same code (minus the SOCKS5 negotiation and with the CONNECT request added) using HTTP proxy and it was successful and read the full response data. 

I have also tried turning off the certificate checking, but still hangs on the AuthenticateAsClient call. I'm stumped. Any other ideas?

Comment: @justsomeguy my VB kungfu is rusty, and more so in the context of .NET, I *think* I coded the SOCKS5 protocol correctly per [RFC 1928](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1928), but you should double check it. Did you try sniffing the client's network traffic with a packet sniffer like Wireshark to make sure the sniffer thinks the SOCKS portion is accurate? The SSL portion should work fine provided the SOCKS proxy opens the tunnel and the code reads all reply bytes from the `stream` before initiating the SSL handshake. I've coded SSL over SOCKS before, but not in VB.NET